# Making torrential my default torrent client

Tags: firefox, default

Good morning,

I have installed a Torrential however I am no table to use it.
When I try to download a torrent, Elementary offers the list of torrent clients, but Torrential is not amongst them.
Also, when I try to change defaults in Firefox, I do not see it in the list.

How can I make it default client?
I tried to browse, but I have no clue where it is hiding and what file to select to run it.

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 1):

if you save the torrent file on your pc, then by going to the downloads folder and right-clicking it you can choose which application to open it with. There you should also(however I don't remember how) be able to set it as the default app for that filetype

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend opening an issue on the app's issue queue: 
https://github.com/davidmhewitt/torrential/issues

You could manually select it from the file system by selecting "Choose other Application", navigating to `/usr/bin/` and selecting `com.github.davidmhewitt.torrential`.